# URL shown in browser while editing page source in HTML

Tags: html, browser, inspect

I'm making a tutorial which involves recording my computer screen. I need to click a link that normally directs me to, say `https://website.com/page`. I want it to redirect me to `https://website.com/another_page`, which can be easily edited using Inspect Element.

However, when I click the link showing now `another_page`, I want the URL in browser (Firefox, Chrome) to still be `https://website.com/page`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do fullscreen in which case the url wouldn't even show. I don't know if that would work with your screen recorder, but it's worth a try. You could also the edit the url directly at the top of your screen so that it shows https://website.com/page and move your keyboard focus away from it so that it appears that the url is https://website.com/page.